# Using Tabs as indentation with Cython emacs

Tags: ubuntu

Under my home directory I have a .emacs file which has the following lines -

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")
(require 'cython-mode)
```

and under the .emacs.d directory I have this file - cython-mode.el which I downloaded from here - [Cython-mode.el](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Tools/cython-mode.el) and I have been using emacs with Cython for over a week now but I cannot seem to do a tab. When I hit tab it does not indent at all. Where am I going wrong ?

Sample example -

```
cdef extern from "Skip_list.cpp":
pass
```

The pass word should come under extern but it does not. I am not able to figure out why.

OS - Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Cython 0.24 , Emacs version - 25.2

**UPDATE**

When I type M-x cython-mode the word "pass" does get indented properly but I get this message at the bottom of emacs. Why is this not done automatically and does this mean I have to do it manually every single time ?

**Can't guess python-indent-offset ,using defaults : 4**

I also did a

```
 find . -name "python.el"
```

and

```
 find . -name "python-mode.el"
```

as user root on my Ubuntu and both these finds gave me null results.

Comment: You can use M-x`locate-library` to tell you exactly where
Emacs is getting a particular library from. In your case it's possible
that you only have the compiled versions, which would all be filenames
ending in `.elc`

Comment: @rpluim - Excellent point. There is indeed a python.elc. How do you suggest I fix my problem ?

Comment: I don't think there's a problem to fix, unless you're unhappy with python-mode's default of 4 space indenting. If you're referring to having to type M-x`cython-mode`, then you should investigate the documentation of the variable `auto-mode-alist`

Comment: @rpluim I read about it but I am not sure how it will help ensure that my Cython code is indented properly

Comment: You said that indentation happens as intended after you do M-x`cython-mode`, which indicates your buffer is not being put in `cython-mode` automatically. `auto-mode-alist` is a way of indicating which modes gets used based on the name of the file you're editing.

Comment: @rpluim can you help ? On my Ubuntu 18.04 machine Emacs mode for cython is simply unusable. It does not recognize any indentation.